# Could you replace these words with simple words? "rent strike" and " mount".

Tags: single-word-requests

The leader of the rent strike mounted the platform to deliver an effective philippic against the management.

NB I should say I looked them up in dictionaries but still I have my doubts if the word "mount" refers to plan something. I also have my doubts if " rent strike" means protest against raising cost of renting houses, does it?

Answer (score 1):

"Mount" here refers to the act of getting up onto something in the same sense as "mounting a horse"; the leader "mounted a platform", that is, he stepped or climbed up onto a raised surface in order to give his speech.

And yes, a 'rent strike' is a coordinated protest against a hike in the cost of renting a house.

Comment: [Rent strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent_strike) *can* be a protest against high rent, but it also relates to other complaints: *Historically, rent strikes have often been used in response to problems such as high rents, poor conditions in the property, or unreasonable tenancy demands; however, there have been situations where wider issues have led to such action*